# Bind to an expression to evaluate

Tags: java, binding, javafx-2

With JavaFX2 I have this code:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource("App.fxml"));
TabPane tabPane = (TabPane) loader.getNamespace().get("tabPane");
Tab tab = (Tab) loader.getNamespace().get("closeAllTab");
```

Now I'm looking to disable `tab` when `tabPane` has less than 3 tabs (tabs can be closed). I need a binding like this:

```
 tab.disableProperty().bind(tabPane.disableProperty());
```

but, of course, I need to evaluate `tabPane.getTabs().size()`. How to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using `ObservableList` bindings:

```
tabPane.getTabs().addListener(new ListChangeListener() {
    public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends E> c) {
        tabPane.setDisabled(tabPane.getSize() < 3);
    }
});
```

Java 8 form:

```
tabPane.getTabe().addListener(e -> tabPane.setDisabled(tabPane.getSize() < 3));
```